# R package GitLab pipeline fails at the codecov stage but not in the R check (as-cran)

Tags: r, gitlab-ci, r-package

I am running two pipeline stages on my GitLab cl (homemade Docker contatiner with R-base on Ubuntu:16.04). The only track of the error is in the codecov step (while R check is successful). This is the error message and command (on GitLab):

```
$ Rscript -e 'covr::package_coverage(type="tests", quiet = FALSE)'
  (...)
  * DONE (mypkg)
  Running specific tests for package ‘mypkg’
    Running ‘testthat.R’
  Error: Failure in `/tmp/RtmpGgElCC/R_LIBS94b18abb4/mypkg/mypkg-tests/testthat.Rout.fail`
```

As usual, I can not replicate this error locally. No other message related to the error is shown. Moreover, I can not find a way to retrieve that log file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Codecov token:

```
# your .gitlab-ci.yml, ending with:
- apt-get install —yes git 
- R -e 'covr::codecov(token = "yourtoken")'
```

Get your token from https://codecov.io/your_name/your_project/settings.

See my own implementation at https://gitlab.com/msberends/AMR :)